# How to secure a good safe mode when MOSFET burns open circuit

Tags: mosfet, fuses, incandescent

I am working on a circuit like this one:

[image: In the circuit the PMOS **Q1** is normally closed, and all energy the from the source runs through the resistor **R2**. If the photo sensor **D2** detects that the LED **D1** is not emitting light, it will pull down the gate on **Q1**, which will pull a lot of current through the fuse **F1**, in which case it should blow.]

In the circuit the PMOS **Q1** is normally closed, and all energy from the source **V1** runs through the resistor **R2**. If the photo sensor **D2** detects that the LED **D1** is not emitting light, it will pull down the gate on **Q1**, which will pull a lot of current through the fuse **F1**, in which case the fuse should blow.

The circuit under the red line should have a safe state where there is infinite resistance (*like F1 blowing or R2 burning to an open circuit*).

As it is now, most component failures lead to a controlled failure. I can only think of two where it doesn't work.

The first is if the controller doesn't work probably and holds the Q1 gate voltage high. I am not concerned about this here.

The second is if the MOSFET fails *open-circuit*. In that case i will lose control of the MOSFET and have no way to blow the fuse.

I know MOSFET's normally fail short (*which should blow the fuse*) and that I should have the **I^2t product for fusing** of Q1 higher than that of F1, since this should make the fuse blow before the MOSFET fails. But I don't think that is good enough (*I could be wrong*).

**My question is:**

**Is there a method that could give the right safe state even in the scenario where the MOSFET burns *open circuit*?**

*Side note: The point of the circuit under the red line is to simulate an incandescent light bulb, which can be burst when desired.*

**EDIT: It has been pointed out in the comments that as it was drawn the P channel would conduct heavily through its body diode which will cause the FET to blow or the fuse to blow. The body diode conduction will start at about 700mV even if there is no gs voltage. The circuit has been modified**

Comment: 1) browse this site and the internet and observe how proper schematics are draw. Yours is confusing, with the part above the red dotted line, it has no ground ? 2) why design for failure (and who says the MOSFET will fail open ???) instead of designing properly so that it should not fail (like build in redundancy).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I honestly don't think it is confusing, but your are right in that I could have added a ground to the controller, even though it is totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I would like to design it for failure because it is critical that it fails in a desired way.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You mean I could add another MOSFET in parallel?

Comment: *I honestly don't think it is confusing* Well that is because you **know** how you want the circuit to work. A schematic is a way to communicate that with others who do not know what it is supposed to do. Some conventions need to be followed to make the schematic clear. The level at which you ask questions also means we cannot make assumptions that you do the right thing (like grounding the controller). Some beginners don't see that a common ground is needed. If you know it is there, draw it to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Why are you surprised that MOSFETs can be added in parallel ? It is common practice but usually to distribute power dissipation. But there's no reason not to do the same for reliability.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am not surprised, I just wanted to make sure this was what you were talking about.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok, thank you, I will keep that in mind for any question in the future.

Comment: @EngIntern .Correct your diagram because as drawn the P chan will conduct heavily through its body diode which will cause it to blow or the fuse to blow .Body diode conduction will start at say 700mV even if there is no gs volts .

Comment: Autistic is correct. I VERY STRONGLY recommend you use a symbol which shows the body diode. Moreover, you will never be able to turn on Q1 because it is PMOS, the source is grounded, and you have no negative voltage anywhere in your schematic.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no hazard when Q1 fails open. If you explain what the hazard is, maybe someone would be able to suggest a good way to guard against it. For example, one way to guard against thermal hazards is to use a thermal cutoff (TCO). If V1 current flows through a TCO, and the TCO is in contact with the heat source, the TCO will open in the event of an over-heating fault, and de-energize the device (permanently). Just make sure the TCO is rated for the current and voltage.

Comment: @Autistic Thank you very much, I was not aware of the direction of the body diode. As I understand, this will actually not work at all with a pmos.

Comment: @mkeith I understand now that this is not going to work, because of the body diode and I will look for some other way of setting this up.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for good advice. The hazard if Q1 fails open is that the circuit would behave as a working incandescent bulb, and there would be no way of blowing the fuse. I will have to look into using a TCO, but very good idea.

Comment: BTW what you have here is called a crowbar circuit. You may want to use an SCR instead of a MOSFET. There are lots of examples online. Benefit is once you turn it on it will stay on till the fuse blows no matter what the micro does.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect several MOSFETs in parallel, then it it less likely that they will all fail open.  The level of improvement depends on the cause of failure. If failing open or closed happens at random, then the probability of all failing open falls from \$p\$ to \$p^n\$ with \$n\$ transistors.  If there is a failure mode which always blows the transistor in a way which goes open, and that mode can blow two as easily as one, then there is no improvement.

Comment: But the odds at least one will fail short go up...

Comment: That is a good point.

Comment: parallel is bad... dormant failure.  the fact this thread exists a level of FMEA is being considered